# MVC 4 installation resulting in Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I have an MVC 3 application that uses a Custom Role provider.

```
public class MyRoleProvider : System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
```

I have this setup in the web.config as follows

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="Namespace.MyRoleProvider, NameSpace"  connectionStringName="MembershipDBConnStrName" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This was all working fine until, well I decided to install MVC 4 to playaround with it.

Now my mvc 3 app is not loading with a configuration error that points to my custom role provider

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
Line 81:       <providers>
Line 82:         <clear />
Line 83:         **<add name="MyRoleProvider" type="Namespace.MyRoleProvider, Namespace"     connectionStringName="MembershipDBConnStrName" />**
Line 84:       </providers>
Line 85:     </roleManager>
```

Doing some reading I see some huge changes around membership (namely the simplemembership provider) but I am hoping there is a quick fix for my stuff to continue to work.

Comment: Simplemembership is actually outside of mvc so I don't think that's the issue here

Comment: What did you change in this apps web.config.... Anything after installing mvc4?  Also simplemembership role handling is all done manually so don't think that's it here either.

Comment: @AdamTuliper you are correct about the membership provider, that is probably more of a framework level change. I just saw that and freaked out. I have made no changes in the application or configuration. The only other thing is I did run a big windows update and then mvc4 update. and after that the app stopped working.

Comment: @AdamTuliper I found my issue (saw it in the mirror). I did make a change last night that caused the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try delete all constructors from "MyRoleProvider" class.